# How do I write extendscript code to synchronize two audio clips in PPro based on their audio?

Tags: extendscript, adobe-premiere

I am trying to automate my video editing process and I have to synchronize a video with an audio recording. Manually, this is very easy to do because I can just highlight the two clips in the sequence and synchronize them.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can get extendscript to do this?

I asked ChatGPT for help but I don't think it knows either lol

Comment: How do you intend to match up the two clips (as in, deciding what is synced with what)?  Are they close to each other on separate tracks?  Do they have embedded internal timecodes?

Comment: @SeanMcNally the clips are of a podcast, the audio clip is from the mic and video+audio clip is from the camera. I want to align them based on their audio so that I can use the audio from the mic and just mute the audio from the camera. Unfortunately I can't start recording both at the same time so I have to use the audio waveforms to align them either manually or using the synchronize based on audio function.
Sorry for the long winded response, but I am trying to provide all the info I can. I appreciate any recs you may have!

Comment: Thanks for the info. So the thing is, if you want to automate this, you’ll need to figure out some way of pairing up the audio clips with the video clips they correspond to. If they share part of a name, that’s great, but I’m guessing the audio clips probably come from something like a zoom recorder, and the names are totally different. And if you have to do that pairing manually…well, it’s not that much more work to just press synchronize inside your bin and create a merged clip. Figuring out a pairing method that works with your specific project is a good start